# Fill a matrix with the informations contained in an Array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, matrix

How to fill a matrix with the informations contained in an Array:

eg. 'matrix' is a matrix of Strings.

```
String[] form = {"hey", "guys", "how", "are", "you", "bye"} //the size is 3*2

for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        matrix[k][x] = form[...]
```

how could I iterate properly on the list 'form' to fill the matrix?

I would like to receive something like:

```
hey guys how 
are you bye
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arithmetic to convert row `k` and column `x` to a position in the array.

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        matrix[k][x] = form[3*k + x]
```